# swift app crash - debugger providing wrong crash location

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, swift

Am attempting to learn Swift and am building an audio application inside of OSX.

I am attempting to debug the code, and I am experiencing the following error:

```
ESX_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) at runtime during debugging.
```

No further information is available from the debugger.

Now, of course I would normally be hard at work by this point googling for a solution, but there is more information...

The function in which this error appears is fairly large, and the debugger line is about 3 lines of code from the top of the function.

Problem is, that the crash happens way down inside the function - in the main loop, and after it has run over 80 times. The debugger appears to be moving its pointer back earlier in the code which is pretty confusing. I can confirm that the execution thread is way further on than the position in the code where the crash is being reported.

Due to the fact that the stack location is incorrect, all the debug variables are missing in the debugger.

Can the debugger be forced to report the correct stack location?

Comment: If the app doesn't crash until you've reached the loop, set some breakpoints, that'll let you debug at that location, even before the crash has occurred.

Comment: The debugger actually jumps out of the loop and indicates a crash on a much earlier part of the code. I can walk through the code, but at some point it will jump out of the loop and jump to the 3rd line of the function.